# Почему Bower выдает ошибку "throw error;"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower

**У меня есть проект, который находиться на диске "E" и bower работает отлично.**

```
PS E:\Все для Web Верстки\Project\Toy> bower init
bower existing      The existing bower.json file will be used and filled in
? name (toy)
```

**В аналогично проекте на диске "C" выдает ошибку.**

```
PS C:\Users\khdev\Desktop\test> bower init
C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:92
                throw error;
                ^

Error: C:\Users\khdev\.bowerrc should not be a directory
    at C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:90:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at json (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:87:14)
    at rc (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\rc.js:34:13)
    at Config.load (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-config\lib\Config.js:16:20)
    at readCachedConfig (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:15:39)
    at defaultConfig (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\khdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
PS C:\Users\khdev\Desktop\test>
```

> .bowerrc

```
{
    "directory": "app/libs"
}
```

**Диск "C" основной. Проекты идентичны, хотя это не имеет значения, ибо я пробовал в любой директории развернуть Bower. Играет роль на каком диске его разворачивать. Запускал консоль через права Администратора, и это тоже не помогло.**

[image: Структура проекта]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Проблема заключалась в том, что в папке khdev была папка с названием ".bowerrc".**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]